# Encountered the symbol "}" when expecting one of the following:

Tags: plsql

I'm using PL/SQL developer to créate this trigger, I read somewhere that it could be a CR-LF missinterpretation by Oracle, but it is the first time this occurs. Below the code is the Error log:

---

```
    create or replace trigger Terreno_nomenc
  before update of circ_prov,sector_prov,cod_div_prov,nro_div_prov,nro_parc_prov on adminmo.terreno  
  for each row
declare

  circ integer:= 0;
  sector integer:= 0;
  cod_div integer:= 0;
  nro_div integer:= 0;
  nro_par integer:= 0;

  nueva_nomenc varchar2(18)  := ' ';
  vieja_nomenc varchar2(18)  := ' ';
  dominio integer:= 0;

begin
        vieja_nomenc:= :old.nomenc; 
        if (:new.circ_prov <> :old.circ_prov) then {

                                                   circ := :new.circ_prov;
           }
         else {
               circ := :old.circ_prov;
         }
         end if;
         if(:new.sector_prov <> :old.sector_prov) then {
                                                       sector := :new.sector_prov;
         }
         else {
               sector := :old.sector_prov;
         }
         end if;
         if(:new.cod_div_prov <> :old.cod_div_prov) then {
                                                         cod_div := :new.cod_div_prov;
         }
         else{
              cod_div := :old.cod_div_prov;
         }
         end if;
         if(:new.nro_div_prov <> :old.nro_div_prov) then {
                                                          nro_div := :new.nro_div_prov;
         }
         else{
              nro_div := :old.nro_div_prov;
         }
         end if;
         if(:new.nro_parc_prov <> :old.nro_parc_prov) then {
                                                            nro_par := :new.nro_parc_prov;
         }
         else{
              nro_par := :old.nro_parc_prov;
         }
         end if;
         if(circ > 0 and sector > 0 and cod_div > 0 and nro_div > 0) {

                 nueva_nomenc := to_char(circ,'999') || '-' || to_char(sector,'99') || '-' || to_char(cod_div,'99') || '-' || to_char(nro_div,'9999') || '-' || to_char(nro_par, '999');

                 select t.refnro into dominio 
                 from geoimax.comodoro_ejido_dom_ref t
                 where t.reftex = vieja_nomenc;

                 update terreno set nomenc = nueva_nomenc where terreno.subsistema = :new.subsistema and terreno.partida = :new.partida;

                 update geoimax.Comodoro_Ejido_Dom_Ref c set c.reftex = nueva_nomenc where c.refnro = dominio;
         }
         end if;
end Terreno_nomenc;
```

---

Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "{" when expecting one of the following:

```
      ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
      raise return select update while with <an identifier>
      <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
      continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
      savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
   The symbol "begin was inserted before "{" to continue.
```

Line: 19
Text: if (:new.circ_prov <> :old.circ_prov) then {

Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "}" when expecting one of the following:

```
      ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
      null pragma raise return select update while with
      <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
      <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock
      insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
      merge pipe purge
```

Line: 21
Text: }

Comment: i'm not sure you need the curly braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of errors:

1. {} curly braces should be removed.
2. THEN missed out in one of the IF statements.

---

```
CREATE OR replace TRIGGER terreno_nomenc
  BEFORE UPDATE OF circ_prov, sector_prov, cod_div_prov, nro_div_prov,
nro_parc_prov ON adminmo.terreno
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    circ         INTEGER := 0;
    sector       INTEGER := 0;
    cod_div      INTEGER := 0;
    nro_div      INTEGER := 0;
    nro_par      INTEGER := 0;
    nueva_nomenc VARCHAR2 ( 18 ) := ' ';
    vieja_nomenc VARCHAR2 ( 18 ) := ' ';
    dominio      INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
    vieja_nomenc := :OLD.nomenc;

    IF ( :NEW.circ_prov <> :OLD.circ_prov ) THEN
      circ := :NEW.circ_prov;
    ELSE
      circ := :OLD.circ_prov;
    END IF;

    IF ( :NEW.sector_prov <> :OLD.sector_prov ) THEN
      sector := :NEW.sector_prov;
    ELSE
      sector := :OLD.sector_prov;
    END IF;

    IF ( :NEW.cod_div_prov <> :OLD.cod_div_prov ) THEN
      cod_div := :NEW.cod_div_prov;
    ELSE
      cod_div := :OLD.cod_div_prov;
    END IF;

    IF ( :NEW.nro_div_prov <> :OLD.nro_div_prov ) THEN
      nro_div := :NEW.nro_div_prov;
    ELSE
      nro_div := :OLD.nro_div_prov;
    END IF;

    IF ( :NEW.nro_parc_prov <> :OLD.nro_parc_prov ) THEN
      nro_par := :NEW.nro_parc_prov;
    ELSE
      nro_par := :OLD.nro_parc_prov;
    END IF;

    IF ( circ > 0
         AND sector > 0
         AND cod_div > 0
         AND nro_div > 0 ) THEN
      nueva_nomenc := To_char (circ, '999')
                      || '-'
                      || To_char (sector, '99')
                      || '-'
                      || To_char (cod_div, '99')
                      || '-'
                      || To_char (nro_div, '9999')
                      || '-'
                      || To_char (nro_par, '999');

      SELECT T.refnro
      INTO   dominio
      FROM   geoimax.comodoro_ejido_dom_ref T
      WHERE  T.reftex = vieja_nomenc;

      UPDATE terreno
      SET    nomenc = nueva_nomenc
      WHERE  terreno.subsistema = :NEW.subsistema
             AND terreno.partida = :NEW.partida;

      UPDATE geoimax.comodoro_ejido_dom_ref C
      SET    C.reftex = nueva_nomenc
      WHERE  C.refnro = dominio;
    END IF;
END terreno_nomenc; 
/
```

Comment: Thank you...i've read this example on if-then-else statements and it's shown with curly brackets:IF condition THEN
   {...statements...}

ELSE
   {...statements...}

END IF;

Answer (score 3):

You don't use curly brackets in PL/SQL.  None of the `{` or `}` characters in your code are needed and all of them are syntax errors.  You'll need to remove all those characters.

Once you do that, you may still get syntax errors (since you didn't post your table definitions, we have no way to try to fix the trigger and verify that it compiles on our system).  But they'll at least be different errors.

On closer inspection, you also appear to have an `UPDATE` statement in the trigger that is trying to update rows in the table that the row-level trigger is defined on.  The trigger is trying to update `terreno` and is defined on a table `terreno` (unless you have two tables with the same name in different schemas and you are being very tricky with name resolution).  That's going to throw a mutating table error when you try to run it.  Are you actually trying to modify the current row that is being updated?  Or are you trying to update other rows in the table?  If the latter, that strongly implies that the data model is incorrect because that implies that data in one row depends on data in other rows of the same table which violates basic normalization.

If you are merely trying to modify data in the current row, don't use an `UPDATE`.  Simply modify the `:new` pseudorecord.

```
:new.nomenc := nueva_nomenc;
```

Comment: Thank you...i've read this example on if-then-else statements and it's shown with curly brackets:IF condition THEN {...statements...} ELSE {...statements...} END IF

Comment: @user2799472 - Then you were either reading something that pertained to some other language or the reference is blindingly incorrect or you are misinterpreting something.  You would never use a `{` or an `}` in PL/SQL to identify the beginning or end of sections of code.  There are many languages where you would use those characters, PL/SQL is not one of them.

Comment: About the table it's the same, I'm not using other rows of the same table I'm using other columns (of the same row) to calculate another value in the row.

Comment: But yes...it's a mutating table error :D

Comment: @user2799472 - Updated my answer.  Just modify the `:new` pseudorecord.

Comment: @user2799472: I'm absolutely, totally sure the PL/SQL does not have **any** curly braces in it to define blocks. Why don't you start with the real reference first because relying on some third-party websites?

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name: Good sugestion, im folowing it. Justin Cave: Thank you, sometimes i just burn out